# Are Facebook iOS app posts drawn with CoreGraphics?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, core-graphics

Does anyone know how the Facebook app for iOS displays the post items?

What is the best (most efficient) way to display these post items in an iOS app?

Core graphics? ImageViews?

Thanks

[image: Facebook for iOS]

Comment: Since the facebook app is closed sourced you will never get a real answer to this unless a Facebook developer is will te share the secret. But they have posted some information on the subject:[
Under the hood: Rebuilding Facebook for iOS](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-rebuilding-facebook-for-ios/10151036091753920)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using a custom `UITableView`

> Finally, when you start Facebook for iOS, you want to see your news feed, not a loading spinner. To provide the best experience possible, we now show previously-cached content immediately. But this introduces a new problem: If you have a lot of stories in your news feed, UITableView throws a small spanner in the works by calling the delegate method -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: for each story in your news feed in order to work out how tall to make its scrollbar. This would result in the app loading all the story data from disk and calculating the entire story layout solely to return the height of the story, meaning startup would get progressively slower as you accumulate more stories.

You can read more details about the ObjectiveC Facebook Version here: https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-rebuilding-facebook-for-ios/10151036091753920 (This is also aboves cite source)

Comment: So a `UITableView` can be customized that flexibly?

Comment: Yes of course there many examples on the web.
Here's one which doesn't even require much coding: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: Thanks for all the help! :) I'm quite new to Objective-C...

Comment: Don't worry. Welcome ;)